# I m trying to list a class object inside a class object in asp.net webservice using c#

Tags: asp.net

I have to define class data and make it a list. I have a ItemDetails class,i have to define it's datamembers in InvoiceRoot Class. When i'm defining it's data seperately it's working fine and making list. But when I do it insidethe class object of InvoiceRoot class,it doesn't work the for loop doesn't work. So How can I make the list of ItemDetails datamembers

Here I make the list by initializing the class object separately:

```
  List<ItemDetails> ItemLists = new List<ItemDetails>();
        for (int i = 0; i < serial_no; i++)
        {

            ItemLists.Add(new ItemDetails
            {
                SlNo = (string)All_SerialNo[i],
                PrdDesc = null,
                IsServc = item_isservice,
                HsnCd = item_hsncode[i].ToString(),
                Barcde = null,
                Qty = Convert.ToDecimal(item_quantity[i].ToString()),
                FreeQty = Convert.ToDecimal(item_freeqty[i].ToString()),
                Unit = null,
                UnitPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(item_rate[i].ToString()),
                TotAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(item_total_price[i].ToString()),
                Discount = Convert.ToDecimal(item_discount[i].ToString()),
                PreTaxVal = Convert.ToDecimal(item_taxable_amount[i].ToString()),
                AssAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(item_taxable_amount[i].ToString()) - Convert.ToDecimal(item_discount[i].ToString()),
                GstRt = 9,
                IgstAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(item_IGST_Amt[i].ToString()),
                CgstAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(item_CGST_Amt[i].ToString()),
                SgstAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(item_SGST_Amt[i].ToString()),
                CesRt = 0,
                CesAmt = 0,
                OthChrg = 0,
                StateCesRt = 0,
                StateCesAmt = 0,
                StateCesNonAdvlAmt = 0,
                TotItemVal = item_totalvalue[i].ToString(),
                OrdLineRef = null,
                OrgCntry = null,
                PrdSlNo = null,
                BchDtls = null,
            });
        }
```

Here I am trying make the list inside the InvoiceRoot class object

```
  InvoiceRoot invoice = new InvoiceRoot
        {
                Version = "1.1",
                DocDtls = new DocumentDetails
                {
                    Typ = "Invoice",
                    No = invoice_no.ToString(),
                    Dt = invoice_date
                },
               ItemList = new List<ItemDetails>
                {
                   
                   new ItemDetails
                   {
                       for (int i = 0; i < serial_no; i++)
                          {

                            ItemLists.Add(new ItemDetails
                               {
                                 SlNo = (string)All_SerialNo[i],
                                 PrdDesc = null,
                                 IsServc = item_isservice,
                                 HsnCd = item_hsncode[i].ToString(),
                                 Barcde = null,
                                 Qty = Convert.ToDecimal(item_quantity[i].ToString()),
                                 FreeQty = Convert.ToDecimal(item_freeqty[i].ToString()),
                                 Unit = null,
                                 UnitPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(item_rate[i].ToString()),
                                 TotAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(item_total_price[i].ToString()),
                                 Discount = Convert.ToDecimal(item_discount[i].ToString()),
                                 PreTaxVal = Convert.ToDecimal(item_taxable_amount[i].ToString()),
                                 AssAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(item_taxable_amount[i].ToString()) - Convert.ToDecimal(item_discount[i].ToString()),
                                 GstRt = 9,
                                 IgstAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(item_IGST_Amt[i].ToString()),
                                 CgstAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(item_CGST_Amt[i].ToString()),
                                 SgstAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(item_SGST_Amt[i].ToString()),
                                 CesRt = 0,
                                 CesAmt = 0,
                                 OthChrg = 0,
                                 StateCesRt = 0,
                                 StateCesAmt = 0,
                                 StateCesNonAdvlAmt = 0,
                                 TotItemVal = item_totalvalue[i].ToString(),
                                 OrdLineRef = null,
                                 OrgCntry = null,
                                 PrdSlNo = null,
                                 BchDtls = null,
                              });
                           }
               }
```

I Want Such Output:

```
[
{
 "Version":"1.1",
 "DocDtls": {
    "Typ": "Invoice",
    "No": "6",
    "Dt": "4/1/2022"
  },
 "ItemList":[{
"SlNo": "9",
    "PrdDesc": null,
    "IsServc": "Y",
    "HsnCd": "22029030",
    "Barcde": null,
    "Qty": 1.0,
    "FreeQty": 0.0,
    "Unit": null,
    "UnitPrice": 600.84,
    "TotAmt": 600.84,
    "Discount": 0.00,
    "PreTaxVal": 600.84,
    "AssAmt": 600.84,
    "GstRt": 9,
    "IgstAmt": 0.0,
    "CgstAmt": 36.05,
    "SgstAmt": 36.05,
    "CesRt": 0,
    "CesAmt": 0,
    "OthChrg": 0,
    "StateCesRt": 0,
    "StateCesAmt": 0,
    "StateCesNonAdvlAmt": 0,
    "TotItemVal": "672.94",
    "OrdLineRef": null,
    "PrdSlNo": null,
    "OrgCntry": null,
    "BchDtls": null,
    "Attributedetails": null
  },
  {
    "SlNo": "10",
    "PrdDesc": null,
    "IsServc": "Y",
    "HsnCd": "22029090",
    "Barcde": null,
    "Qty": 3.0,
    "FreeQty": 0.0,
    "Unit": null,
    "UnitPrice": 1641.38,
    "TotAmt": 4924.14,
    "Discount": 0.00,
    "PreTaxVal": 4924.14,
    "AssAmt": 4924.14,
    "GstRt": 9,
    "IgstAmt": 0.0,
    "CgstAmt": 295.45,
    "SgstAmt": 295.45,
    "CesRt": 0,
    "CesAmt": 0,
    "OthChrg": 0,
    "StateCesRt": 0,
    "StateCesAmt": 0,
    "StateCesNonAdvlAmt": 0,
    "TotItemVal": "5515.04",
    "OrdLineRef": null,
    "PrdSlNo": null,
    "OrgCntry": null,
    "BchDtls": null,
    "Attributedetails": null
  }
]
}
]
```

Comment: Create and fill the `ItemLists` before you intiailize InvoiceRoot and store it in a variable. Then you can assign it to `InvoiceRoot.ItemList`

Comment: if i'm not wrong I will still need to use the loop

Comment: Sure, but you cannot use a loop in the object initializer

Comment: then how would i do that